# (m/regexp/) or {multiple ; commands; after; or; }

Tags: perl, error-handling

I like very much this syntax:

```
try_something() or warn "Cant do it";
```

How can I add more commands after `or`?

For example it would be useful in this code:

```
foreach (@array)
{
   m/regex/ or {warn "Does not match"; next;}  # this syntax is wrong
   ...
}
```

One way I found is

```
try_something() or eval {warn "Can't do it"; next;};
```

but I think it is bad idea.

BEST ANSWERS:

1. `do` is better than `eval`.
2. The comma operator is even better: `do_smth() or warn("Does not match"), next;` Nota bene: parentheses are mandatory for `warn` so that `next` does not parse as one of its arguments.

Comment: Although you'll get some answers on how to do this, I'd strongly recommend that you **dont** do it. It lacks clarity. Using and explicit if is more appropriate given that you wish to execute a block of code based in the truth of a Boolean expression. Perl offers many elegant ways to express intent, but one can easily get carried away and write very obscure code, very quickly.

Comment: Comma operator is rarely better. It is *far* less readable. It does work in this very limited situation, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the case in your question, I would use `unless`.

```
for (@array) {
  unless (/regex/) {
    warn "Does not match";
    next;
  }

  ...
}
```

You can sometimes get away with using the [comma operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Comma-Operator). It evaluates its left-hand argument, throws away the result, evaluates the right-hand argument and returns that result. Applied to your situation it looks like

```
for (@array) {
  /regex/ or warn("Does not match"), next;

  ...
}
```

Note the extra parentheses. You have to be a bit more careful about parentheses and grouping this way. Be judicious in your use of this technique: it can get ugly quickly.

In a comment below, Zaid suggests

```
warn('Does not match'), next unless /regex/;
```

The choice is a matter of style. Perl was created by a linguist. Natural languages allow us to express the same thought in different ways depending on which part we want to emphasize. In your case, do you want to emphasize the warning or the pattern match? Place the more important code out front.

Comment: !! excellent and beauty, thanks a lot. But why parentheses become mandatory here (I've check - "warn" does't work without parentheses, but "next" does )?

Comment: @user1423646 because warn is a listop, so without parentheses, `next` becomes an argument to `warn`, which means it's evaluated before `warn`, which means that `warn` never gets a chance to run because `next` changes the control flow before it can.

Comment: Warn takes a list of parameters. Without parentheses, the 'next' looks like a second parameter to warn

Comment: `warn('Does not match'), next unless /regex/;` is another alternative.

Answer (score 6):

I think that will end up being pretty unreadable pretty fast, but you can `do`:

```
foo() or do { bar(); baz(); };
```

```
sub foo {
  return $_[0] == 2;
}

for (1..3) {
  print $_;
  foo($_) or do { print " !foo\n"; next; };
  print " foo!\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out (and tested) that you can also use 'and':

```
try_something() or warn "Cant do it" and print "Hmm." and next;
```

If try_something() is success then it doesn't do anything after or.

If try_something() fails then it warns and prints and next.

Comment: Why this answer is better than another that was accepted by OP?